# How do you reset a relative font-size to not inherit font-size from the html element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-size

Let's say that you have:

- an `html` element styled like StackOverflow styles its `html`, using `var` and `--fs-base` to clamp `font-size`
- a "parent" `div` inside the `html` with a `font-size` of `16px`
- a "child" `div` inside the "parent" `div` with a relative `font-size` of `1rem`
- elements inside the child `div`, in this example `p`, also using relative `font-size`, but with `0.75rem`

```css
html {
  --fs-base: 13px;
  font-size: var(--fs-base);
}

.parent {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run this code snippet and inspect it, you'll see the computed `font-size`:

- `html` - `13px`
- `div.parent` - `16px`
- `div.child` - `13px` (but I want `16px`)
- `p` - `9.75px` (but I want `12px`)

As you can see, the computed values are different than what I actually want. Unfortunately, just doing `.parent * { font-size: 16px; }` won't fix this issue, and I'm running out of ideas.

How can you still use a relative `font-size` in `div.child` while ensuring that it inherits the base reset `font-size: 16px` declared in `div.parent`?

Comment: `.child {font-size:1.23rem}` or `.child {font-size:1em}`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, If you use `em`, you can do it as you want.
For example:

```css
html {
  --fs-base: 13px;
  font-size: var(--fs-base);
}

.parent {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>The text into the parent class</span>
  <div class="child">
    <span>The text into the child class</span>
    <p>The text that specified with p tag style</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can you still use a relative font-size in div.child while ensuring that it inherits the base reset font-size: 16px declared in div.parent?"*

| Unit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `em` | A relative unit that is based on the `font-size` of it's parent. |
| `rem` | A relative unit that is based on the `font-size` of root. |

For `.child` `font-size` should be `1em` to have the exact `font-size` of `.parent`. If you want `.child` to be 16px and inherit from root, it'll be `font-size: 1.24rem`.

If you want a real default `font-size` use the `:root` selector which sets the style of `<html>` (aka root, aka `.documentElement`) with a higher priority than `html` selector (see **Figure I**)

**Figure I**

```css
:root {font-size:16px} // This has higher priority
html {font-size:13px}
```

In the example below, click the button to see the difference between root `font-size` `13px` and `16px`. The JavaScript is for demonstration purposes only.

```js
/* All JavaScript is for demonstration purposes only*/
const fsBase = document.getElementById('fsBase');
const reset = document.getElementById('reset');
const root = document.documentElement;

const noFS = `font-size: 16px`;
let flag = false;

fsBase.onclick = e => {
  if (!flag) {
    root.style.cssText = noFS;
    flag = true;
    return;
  }
  flag = false;
  root.style.cssText = '';
}
```

```css
html {
  --fs-base: 13px;
  font-size: var(--fs-base);
}

.parent {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.base1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

p {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.base16 {
  font-size: 1.24rem
}
```

```html
<style></style>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Inherit from .parent 1em
    <p class='base1'>Inherit from .child 1em</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Inherit from root 0.75rem</p>
<p class='base16'>Inherit from root 1.24rem</p>
<button id='fsBase'>fsBase</button>
```